# R programming, split data

Tags: r

I have data as follows:

```
ID   age   sugarlevel

123  15      8

456  13      10

789  25      5

...
```

Anyone knows how to use R to split the data according to sugar level (>=7, <7)? Which means should split into two groups:

```
group 1:

ID  age  sugarlevel

123  15      8

456  13      10

...

group 2:

ID  age  sugarlevel

789  25      5

...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can  `split` the dataset by a grouping variable `df1$sugarlevel >=7` (from @nicola's comments)

```
 lst <- setNames(split(df1, df1$sugarlevel >=7), paste0('group',1:2))
 lst
 #$group1
 # ID age sugarlevel
 #3 789  25          5

 #$group2
 #   ID age sugarlevel
 #1 123  15          8
 #2 456  13         10
```

It is better to work with the dataset in the 'list', but if we need to have two sepearate objects in the global environment,

```
 list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
 group1
 #  ID age sugarlevel
 #3 789  25          5
```

Comment: Why `cumsum`? It seems that he just needs two groups, and `split(df1, df1$sugarlevel >=7)` should suffice.

Comment: @nicola Yes, thanks you can post it as a solution.  I will delete this

Comment: No problem, go ahead, just edit your answer. Many times you helped improving my answers :)

Comment: @rmuc8 You are right. the `cumsum` messed up the grouping, and I only noticed after posting the solution:-)

Comment: yes it works! Thanks! but how to put those two groups into new data? $'FALSE' and $'TURE' is the code? @nicola

Comment: @user2774993  Updated the post, please check